# How to intercept alert in the V3 chrome extenson?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Earlier I used to intercept and remove unnecessary alerts in V2.
However no way I'm able to do it in V3.

Earlier I used to do like this:

file:inject.js

```
do_embed_code(injected_code);

function injected_code()
    {   
        var gg_original_alert = window.alert;      

        window.alert =
                function (msg)
                    {
                        console.log("Here is alert msg=", msg);
                    }

    }


function do_embed_code(func_name)
{
    var s = document.createElement('script');   
    s.textContent = '('+func_name.toString ()+')();';
    document.documentElement.appendChild(s);

    console.log("Inject finished", new Date().getTime());
}
```

manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "all_frames": true,

            "matches": ["*://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["inject.js"]
        }
```

What's the way to do?

Comment: Add "world": "MAIN" to the content_scripts declaration, remove do_embed_code, simply call the main function as IIFE: (()=>{ var gg_original....... })()